# Traversing and printing a queue in C behaves differently when input is given by the user

Tags: c, queue, stdin

I apologise if this concept has been explained on SOF before! I believe my case is slightly different and couldn't find a similar question in the website.

Here's the problem:

I'm trying to store char arrays (strings) in a Queue structure that I'm trying to implement.
The structure and its functions seem to work fine when I hardcode the data myself like this:

```
#include "Time.h"
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){

    struct Queue* q = CreateQueue();
    Enqueue(q, "element1");
    Enqueue(q, "element2");
    Enqueue(q, "element3");
    Enqueue(q, "element4");

    PrintAll(q->first); // this outputs all elements and the time they've been in the queue. 

    return 0;
}
```

The output is as expected, a list of all 4 elements.
However, as soon as I put a simple menu together, to capture the data from the user instead of it being hardcoded as above, the PrintAll() function outputs a duplicate of the very last element enqueued. You also notice that I am timing each node to keep a track on when it was added to the queue and that seem to work fine. Although the ouput shows the last element entered duplicated N times (N being the size of the queue) the timer seems to show correctly for each node!

I am suspecting it's to do with the stdin stream that is not being cleaned but I thought I handled that with a block of code that is shown in main() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>



int main(void){

    char name[31];
    char c;
    int option;
    int ch;
    struct Queue* q = CreateQueue();

    do
    {

        printf("\n 1. Add a an element to the queue");
        printf("\n 2. Print all elements");
        printf("\n 0. Exit");

        printf("\n Please select an option");

        while(scanf("%d", &option)!=1){
        puts("Value non good");
         ch=getchar();
                while(ch!=EOF && ch!='\n'){
                ch=getchar();
                }
        }

        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                ch=getchar();
                while(ch!=EOF && ch!='\n')
                {
                    ch=getchar();
                }
                printf("Please enter the name of the element.\n ");
                fgets(name,30,stdin);

                Enqueue(q, name);
                PrintAll(q->first);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                PrintAll(q->last);
                break;
            }
            default:
                return 0;
        }

    }while(option != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody please shed light on the problem ? I would appreciate it.

here's the rest of the code:

**Time.c:**

```
#include "Time.h"

struct Queue* CreateQueue()
{
    struct Queue* q = malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));
    q->first = NULL;
    q->last = NULL;
    q->size = 0;
    return q;
}


void Enqueue(struct Queue* queue, char* string)
{
    struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->student = string;
    newNode->start_time = time(0);

    if(queue->size == 0)
    {
        queue->first = newNode;

    }
    else
    {
        queue->last->next = newNode;
    }
    queue->last = newNode;
    queue->size = queue->size + 1;
}

char* Dequeue(struct Queue* queue)
{
    if (queue->size < 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    char* toBeRemoved = queue->first->student;
    struct Node* oldNode = queue->first;
    queue->first = oldNode->next;
    queue->size = queue->size - 1;
    if(queue->size == 0)
    {
        queue->last = NULL;
    }
    free(oldNode);
    return toBeRemoved;

}

int IsEmpty(struct Queue *q)
{
    return q->size == 0;
}


char* Peek(struct Queue *q)
{
    return q->first->student;
}



void PrintOne(struct Node *node)
{
    if(node !=NULL)
    {
        int elapsed = ElapsedTime(node);
        printTime(elapsed, node->student);
        //printf("%s\n", node->student);
    }
}

void PrintAll(struct Node* node)
{
    if (node !=NULL)
    {
        PrintAll(node->next);
        PrintOne(node);
    }
}


// returns the waiting time for a student node.
int ElapsedTime(struct Node* node)
{
    int elapsed;
    time_t stop_time;
    stop_time = time(NULL);
    elapsed = difftime( stop_time , node->start_time );

    return elapsed;
}

void printTime(int elapsed, char* student_name)
{
        printf("%s : waiting for ", student_name);
        int minutes_or_hours = 0; //Stores a zero to indicate that it is not neccesary to print minutes or hours.
        //Stores a one to indicate that hours and/or minutes have been printed.

        if( (elapsed / 3600) >= 1)
        {
                int hours = elapsed/3600;
                if(hours == 1)
                {
                        printf("1 hour, ");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("%d hours, ", hours);
                }
                elapsed = elapsed - (hours*3600);

                minutes_or_hours = 1;
        }

        if( (elapsed / 60) >= 1)
        {
                int minutes = elapsed/60;
                if(minutes == 1)
                {
                        printf("1 minute, ");
                }
                else
                {
                        printf("%d minutes, ", minutes);
                }
                minutes_or_hours = 1;

                elapsed = elapsed - (minutes*60);
        }

        if(minutes_or_hours == 1)
        {
                printf("and ");
        }

        printf("%d seconds\n", elapsed);
}
```

**Time.h:**

```
#ifndef TIME_H_
#define TIME_H_
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>



struct Node
{
    time_t start_time;
    struct Node* next;
    char* student;
};

struct Queue
{
    int size;
    struct Node* first;
    struct Node* last;
};

struct Queue* CreateQueue();
void Enqueue(struct Queue* , char* );
char* Dequeue(struct Queue* );
int IsEmpty(struct Queue *);
char* Peek(struct Queue *);
void PrintOne(struct Node *);
void PrintAll(struct Node *);
int ElapsedTime(struct Node* );
void printTime(int , char* );

#endif /* TIME_H_ */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `Enqueue()` you have only copied the string pointer to your structure. In your first case that works, because all the four strings have different pointers to string literals. But in your second example, you are storing the pointer of your data entry `name`, and the contents of this string change with each entry. Each structure store the same pointer, so all point to the most recent string you typed in. If your struct stored the actual string, it would work (but you need to be careful with string lengths).

```
struct Node
{
    time_t start_time;
    struct Node* next;
    char student[31];
};

void Enqueue(struct Queue* queue, char* string)
{
    ...
    strncpy (newNode->student, 30, string);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this. You are totally right, I didn't even think about that. It's all working fine now. I can also assure you that after hours of frustration, I will not forget this concept in the future haha
Cheers.